# Globally constant vector field in a curved spacetime

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature, vector-fields, topology

Is it possible to define a globally constant vector field in a curved spacetime, that is a vector field for which the covariant derivative vanishes along every world line? The vector field $V^{\mu}=0$ would be one example, but are there other examples. Intuitively I would guess there are no other examples since going around loop on which a vector is parallel transported already leads to the fact that one ends up with a different vector than with which one started.

Comment: Let $X(t)=x^{i}(t)(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}})_{c(t)}$ where $X(t)$ is the tangent vector field defined on c(t) a parameterized curve on the manifold. Then the covariant derivative $\frac {DX}{dt}=0$. When say constant, constant relative to what? And by space-time do you mean a semi-Riemannian manifold?

Comment: I mean a  semi-Riemannian manifold and by constant I mean, that the covariant derivative vanishes along every path. Parallel transport along a path can be understood as holding a vector constant along that path.

Comment: A weaker condition, that the symmetrization of the covariant derivative should vanish, is (equivalent to) the definition of a Killing vector field https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field Killing vector fields may or may not exist, depending on the metric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important concept to reason about these things is [*holonomy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy), which describes how the tangent space at a given point transforms by parallel transport along the closed path starting and ending at this point. For orientable Lorentzian manifold holonomy is an element of a Lorentz group $SO(1,3)$. All such elements, for all the paths comprise the *holonomy group* of a given manifold. For a “generic” curved spacetime holonomy group is the whole Lorentz group, but if the holonomy group is the proper subgroup we have a manifold of *special holonomy*. If the action of holonomy group leaves fixed a vector then there is a nontrivial *parallel vector field* which is precisely the object OP is interested in. Of course, since the full Lorentz group does not have invariant subspaces only special holonomy manifolds could  admit parallel vector field.

**Example.** Consider the manifold that is a direct product of curved 3D Riemannian space and a timelike factor $(\mathbb{R},-dt^2)$ . The metric for such a spacetime could be written as: $$ ds^2 = - dt^2 + g^{(3)}_{ij}(X)\,dX^idX^j.$$
It is easy to see that the parallel transport of a vector $A =\alpha\, \partial_t $  ($\alpha=\mathrm{const}$) would leave it unchanged. So $A$ is a parallel vector field on this static spacetime.

For Riemannian manifold *de Rham decomposition theorem* is a useful tool in classifying such parallel vector fields and manifolds that admit them, but situation is more complicated in the Lorentzian case. There we have a class of spacetimes with parallel light-like  vector field that has some importance in string/M theory. For a sampler, I suggest looking at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4542) and follow the references.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to define the notion of a 'constant' vector field in curved manifold. This is because the vectors transform differently at different points in such a geometry. Moreover, Cartesian coordinates cannot be introduced globally. This gave rise to the concept of parallel transport. So if we have a vector field and we make a parallel transport, the vectors should change from point to point. However, the covariant derivative of a geodesic along its own tangent vector is always zero: $DV^\mu=0$, where $V^\mu$ is the tangent four-vector. In this sense, a geodesic is the natural extension of the definition of straight line to a curved manifold