# Existence of parallel vector field

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, metric-tensor, vector-fields

Is there any known parallel vector field in a Schwarzschild spacetime? Or any method to identify parallel vector fields in any spacetime, given the metric $g$?

Comment: Does parallel mean $\nabla_Y X=0$ for every vector field $Y$?

Comment: Yes, so I calculated $\nabla_X \partial t$, for example taking $X=\partial t,\partial r,\partial \theta, \partial \phi$ etc.

Comment: I suspect that there are not such parallel fields since there are too many Killing Fields...

Comment: I mean in the Schwarzshild spacetime: moving one of these vectors with the flow of the Killing Fields you should obtain four linearly independent parallel vector fields and  I think it implies that the manifold is locally flat (and we know that this is false)...

Comment: Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant concept is [holonomy group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy) of a spacetime. Holonomy group of a Schwarzschild spacetime coincides with full Lorentz group, so there are no parallel vector fields. See the paper by [Hall & Lonie](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0310076) for more general study of holonomy and  [Rothman et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0008070) for Schwarzschild spacetime specifically.

Also see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/493782/) for more context.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to understand the articles. This is very helpful.